# Copy to next available line in a worksheet

Tags: excel, vba

I fill in a worksheet called "Info" with customer data. I then manually copy the same customer data to another worksheet "Orders". "Orders" contains invoice numbers and a structure like this:

```
      A           D           E               F            H         J
    INVOICE   FIRSTNAME   LASTNAME        DESCRIPTION   POSTCODE   EMAIL
1    1234       Fred       Smith         Red widget      AR225H   fred@smith.com
2    1235       Bill       Jones         Blue widget     EH66VT   bill@jones.com
3    1236
4    1237
```

I wish to create a macro to copy my data from "Info" to "Orders", cell by cell. I can do this but I need a conditional comment that says "If Orders column D is blank then select row 3 to copy data to". If I don't have this then I overwrite the last order line.

Note that the customer data changes on the "Info" sheet each time, this is why I manually copy it over.

I currently use this formula to pull in the next available invoice number into my Info sheet:

=INDEX(Orders!$A:$A,COUNTA(Orders!$D:$D)+1)

It allows me to have a cell (Say F3) on the "Info" sheet which already contains the right invoice number to allocate for the current customer data. Using this, I could possibly rewrite the condition to "Paste the information into the row where Info!F3 appears in Orders! column A".

Here is the Macro if it helps:

```
Sub Macro2()
'
' Macro2 Macro
'

'
    Range("B6").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Orders").Select
    Range("C735").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Sheets("Info").Select
    Range("B7").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Orders").Select
    Range("D735").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Sheets("Info").Select
    Range("B8").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Info").Select
    Range("B11").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Orders").Select
    Range("E735").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Sheets("Info").Select
    Range("B12").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Orders").Select
    Range("F735").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Sheets("Info").Select
    Range("B15").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Orders").Select
    Range("G735").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Sheets("Info").Select
    ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=-6
    Range("B3").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Orders").Select
    Range("B735").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
End Sub
```

==================

Maybe there's too much info in that question? In its simplest form, all I need is to select a row based on the contents of a cell and then paste information to this row via a macro.

==================

Update - here is the "Info" sheet layout, note that not all rows match columns in the "Orders" sheet:

```
    A                             B                C

                          Invoice number:        1236

Peter 
Parker
12
Overflow Road
Stacktown
BB338J
0121 345 6789
0777 789 789
peter@spidermail.com

Order description:          Red widget
```

Comment: Do you want a macro that effectively takes customer data from your `Info` sheet and paste it into your `Orders` sheet based matching invoice numbers? Example: for invoice number 1237 in `Info` find invoice number 1237 in `Orders` and copy customer data from `Info`?

Comment: @Remnant Yes, that's exactly it. I have a cell with the required invoice number in the Info sheet.

Comment: How is your data structured in the `Info` sheet? Can you add an example like you have done for `Orders`?

Comment: @Remnant Added example and improved "Orders" description.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I like the fictitious address!

I tested this code and it works. You may need to change the cell references, especially in the `Info` sheet to get the right data.

In short, you start on the `Info` sheet, save the relevant data in variables, locate the invoice number in `Orders` and then paste the data.

```
Sub InfoToOrders()
    Dim InvoiceNo As Long, FirstName As String, LastName As String, Description As String, Postcode As String, Email As String

    With Worksheets("Info")
        InvoiceNo = .Range("D1")
        FirstName = .Range("A3")
        LastName = .Range("A4")
        Description = .Range("B13")
        Postcode = .Range("A8")
        Email = .Range("A11")
    End With

    Dim InvoiceNumbers As Range, invoice As Range

    With Worksheets("Orders")

        Set InvoiceNumbers = .Range("A1:A" & .Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row)

        For Each invoice In InvoiceNumbers
            If invoice = InvoiceNo Then
                invoice.Offset(0, 1) = FirstName
                invoice.Offset(0, 2) = LastName
                invoice.Offset(0, 3) = Description
                invoice.Offset(0, 4) = Postcode
                invoice.Offset(0, 5) = Email
            End If
        Next invoice

    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks, I can follow that code. It's not working for me though, seems to be locking on this line: "If invoice = InvoiceNo Then". Not sure why as InvoiceNo is the same as my referenced cell.

Comment: I tested this by adding  Else MsgBox InvoiceNo  before the  End If.

Comment: What does the error message say? `InvoiceNo` is the number on `Info` and `invoice` simply trawls through all invoice numbers on `Orders` to find a match

Comment: I now have this working, it was missing an invoice number further up the page and it seems it couldn't proceed. Thanks so much for your help, very pleased.